# Using reStructuredText (rst) and Sphinx, is there a way to make a list of all the pages that reference (using ref, doc etc) a certain page

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

For example, let's say I have the following project structure

```
/features
 /foo
  index.rst
 /bar
  index.rst
/models
 foo.rst
 bar.rst
```

`/foo/index.rst` contains the following:

```
Foo Feature
***********

A nice explanation of the Foo feature

See :doc:`/models/foo`
```

`/bar/index.rst` contains the following:

```
Bar Feature
***********

A nice explanation of the Bar feature

See :doc:`/models/bar`
```

What I would like is to be able to add a directive to both `/models/foo.rst` and `/models/bar.rst` such that when rendered (with Sphinx), it will generate a link back to the feature page.

For example, my `/models/foo.rst` might contain the following:

```
class Foo {
 id: number;
 title: string;
}

.. magically-insert-back-links: // this is really what i'm looking for
```

And would be rendered as:

```
class Foo {
 id: number;
 title: string;
}

Back Links:

- Foo Feature // and this text would be a link back to the Foo Feature page
```

Comment: Does [cross-referencing syntax](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax) do what you need?

Comment: As far as I can see no. Everything I find on referencing seems to be about inserting **one** link pointing to another document. What I want  to achieve is to use one statement to build a **list** of all links that reference the document that the statement is in. "A list of all the pages that reference this one"

Comment: I've updated the question title to hopefully make it a little more clear